# Install linux-headers on debian unable to locate package

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I am trying to install the linux-headers for my Kernel Version 3.4.61+ and Debian Version 7.1

I typed this Commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

On the last command I always get an Error:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.4.61
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.4.61'
```

btw: It´s all based on a Cubietruck/Cubieboard3

Comment: have you compiled the kernel on your own?

Comment: Use "apt-cache search linux-headers-" to get a list of all available headers, then you can choose one that fits best.

Comment: @hek2mgl sorry i´m complete newb. how can i know that?

Comment: can you show the output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: @Robert i got a list and i chose the first and installed it like that: apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all
I get this Error:
You might want to run apt-get -f install to correct these:
The following package have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all: Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all-armhf (= 3.2.54-2) but it is not going to be installed
openjdk-7-jre-headless: depends: tzdata-java but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try apg-get -f install with no package (or specify a solution)

Comment: @hek2mgl Linux cubieez 3.4.61+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon 23 12:44:19 CST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: @csnewb Please update your question to include the result of `apt-cache search linux-headers`.

Comment: @leeduhem i found the solution. i just typed apt-get -f install
after that i tried again with apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all
voila it worked!

Comment: @csnewb Then it is a broken dependencies problem.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's what you may need to do

```
sudo apt-get update # This will update the repositories list
sudo apt-get upgrade # This will update all the necessary packages on your system
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # This will add/remove any needed packages
reboot # You may need this since sometimes after a upgrade/dist-upgrade, there are some left over entries that get fixed after a reboot
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) # This should work now
```

Comment: 1,000 times yes!

Comment: I did all the things, but still I couldn't.

`root@h1:~# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.4.34-1-pve
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.4.34-1-pve'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.4.34-1-pve'`

Comment: `root@h1:~# apt-get -y install pve-headers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pve-headers`

Comment: Was running into this in Vagrant, and this did the trick! I had to `vagrant reload` after running these commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked (y).

Comment: This along with this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644073/drivers-issue-for-realtek-rtl8723de-wlan-on-debian-10-with-kernel-5-10  just solved a network unclaimed drivers issue for Realtek RTL8723DE wlan on debian 10 with kernel 5.10, which I've been battling with for months now.

Comment: Thank you, works when working with Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 21):

You could search first, then choose the closest one.

For example, on my system:

```
$ apt-cache search linux-headers
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
```

So I can install any one of these three.

Comment: tried to install the first line on my system. got an error posted in comment at my answer to Robert

Answer (score 2):

Heres my experience with this problem:

I installed Kali Linux from a live memory stick. Whilst installing I didn't have an internet connection.

This meant that my sources.list file was set to "Default Off-line Install Values". This meant that when installing I was limited to just the packages and data from the memory stick I Initially installed from.

To fix this, you need to change your sources.list (called switching branches):

Open terminal:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This opens the sources file

Now at the top of the file paste in the following two lines:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.

Now you can type the following commands to update Kali:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

And finally, you should now be able to...

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

This is just my unique experience with this error stemming from an offline install.
I hope this helps someone else out there.

[Reference](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Source.list  file to contain the repository entries. 
You can find them at - https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories.
After editing the file, save it and run "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade". Now run "apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)"

Answer (score 1):

For latest version of kali linux do the following to install vbox guest additions.

1. Update the packages

   ```
   # apt-get update
   ```
2. Command to install virtualbox guest additions

   ```
   # apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
   ```
3. Reboot

   ```
   # reboot
   ```
4. Enjoy!

Now you have successfully installed guest OS additions and you can verify that by toggling full-screen it should now stretch to your screen resolution.

Source: [Kali Linux Official (Docs - VirtualBox guest additions)](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest)

Answer (score 1):

Just Use:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

if you are on a Desktop installation. The apt-get will solve the dependencies and install the correct version of kernel headers.